# How to update the month part only of a date data type

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I tried this:

```
update columnName set field1 = mdy(4,day(field1),year(field1))
```

but didn't worked u_U

I have columns like this: `Day/01/2013` I just need to `Change the month to 06`

Comment: Where are getting the `mdy` definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
update mytable set mydate=date_add(mydate, interval (xxx-month(mydate)) month);
```

where xxx is the month you want to set the date to.

Note, from mysql docs:

> If you add MONTH, YEAR_MONTH, or YEAR and the resulting date has a day
>   that is larger than the maximum day for the new month, the day is
>   adjusted to the maximum days in the new month

Comment: Nice ! But how could I use a `Where` ? I mean, update the month to `4` where the month is `1`. Is it possible ?

Comment: update mytable set mydate=date_add(mydate, interval (xxx-month(mydate)) month) where month(mydate) = 1;